# Import data from excel and exclude/ignore image in header

Tags: python, excel, import

I am trying to import data from a handful of Excel files. All the files have the exact same format. But they all have a little image at the top of the sheet. The image takes up the first 7 rows and 2 columns. I need the data in the 2 columns beneath the picture. I don't need to picture.

Answer (score 1):

Use this option:

```
pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', header=8)
```

When you are giving `header = 8`, It will start reading the data from 8th row.

please refer the [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to know more.

Comment: If this answer works, kindly accept this answer. Its lot for me.:)

Comment: I've tried that already. Sorry, should have mentioned that.
I get the error: "CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4"

And this prints out in my Jupyter notebook above the Traceback:

_locate_stream(Workbook): seen
    0  5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
   20  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2

Comment: Update your question with the error message clearly..